# Redirect Web Page in Bootstrap Modal when clicking outside the modal or pressing escape?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the Twitter Bootstrap modal as a login window, and would like to redirect the user to another website when clicking outside of the modal or when pressing escape. Instead, the default behaviour is just remove the modal and display the original web page.

How could I achieve this scenario by using jquery onclick?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the 'hidden.bs.modal' event on the modal (This event is fired when the modal has finished being hidden from the user (will wait for CSS transitions to complete).

```
 $('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
  window.location.href = ''
});
```

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Answer (score 0):

You could react on the event of closing the modal like this:

```
$('#modalName').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {  
    // redirect
}
```